# Print-only view lays out subviews incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout

I'm trying to print (to PDF) an NSView which is not shown on screen and does not have a parent view.

To show the print dialog I have added the following line to my app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`:

```
[myPrintView print:self];
```

[image: Subviews from bottom to top]

In the print dialog's preview the subviews are show bottom up.  The bottom subview is shown first, then the one which should be above the bottom view etc and the top subview is shown last.

When I add the print view to a scroll view, making it be shown on screen prior to the print call, the order is correct both in the scroll view and the print preview.

```
self.scrollView.documentView = myPrintView;
```

[image: Subviews in correct order]

My I change my print view to not be flipped, it is shown in the correct order in both situations, but it's put on the bottom of the paper.

[image: Correct order but at bottom of page]

How can I resolve this?  Keep it flipped and solve the incorrect order, or keep flipped = NO and use a different method to stick it to the top of the page?

I've added my project to https://bitbucket.org/bpeiren/print-experiments, in case that helps.

Comment: It looks like this is a problem with the layout, rather than the order of the printing. How do you add the views to your print view? Do you call `-setFrame:`? Is Auto Layout turned on?

Comment: Yes I am using Auto Layout.  All the subviews are added in the XIB, except for adding the printview itself to a parent for testing.  I did a search to be sure but nowhere do I set the frame manually.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have ambiguous layout, meaning your nib doesn't have enough constraints to ensure the subviews appear where you want them. The two layouts you're seeing both satisfy the constraints, so you need to constrain more aspects of the layout so the subviews appear just where you want them.

Judging from the two images you posted of your layout, I'd suggest you try:

1. Pinning the top of your top view to the top of the container
2. Pinning the vertical spacing between your top and bottom views

**Added:** I just downloaded [your .xib](https://bitbucket.org/bpeiren/print-experiments/raw/46935c8d1bf17c9ca2094d9bed37b4729eb8df1c/Print%20Experiments/en.lproj/MainMenu.xib) and it's clear that you are constraining the top subview to the top of the view, and the vertical spacing of the subviews, down the page. So that won't fix the problem. Is the height variable? If not, try constraining the height of the container. Why are you enclosing the text and image fields in NSViews? It might be simpler to take them out. (You aren't getting log messages about unsatisfiable constraints, right?)

This WWDC video, [Introduction to Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228) gave the best explanation of ambiguous layout I've seen.

For debugging purposes, you could add the view to a window and then work with the Auto Layout which [this good answer describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8192491/893113).

Alternatively, you could just turn off Auto Layout for this nib. Since your view is simple, you can manage the layout easily enough the old way, with springs and struts.