# How to programmatically define AutoLayout constraint to allow a view to be pinned to the edges of its superview

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5, autolayout

I've just started trying my hands on AutoLayout and don't quite get it.

Can anyone please show me how exactly to *programmatically* pin a view to its superview such that the space between the edges of the view and the edges of the superview is 0. (Essentially, I want the view to still cover the screen when in landscape)

Thanks

in the end, this was how I solved it: (vc.view is the child view and self.view is the parent)

```
    /* pin Left of child to left of parent */
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vc.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0]];

    /* pin Right of child to right of parent */
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vc.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0]];

    /* pin top of child to bottom of nav bar(or status bar if no nav bar) */
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vc.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0]];

    /* pin Top of nav bar to bottom of child view */
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:vc.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0]];
```

Comment: I think this should help.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156799/how-to-make-a-custom-view-resize-with-the-window-with-cocoa-auto-layout

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create forexample two constraints: to the left edge with value = 0 and right edge with value = 0. Also you can create constrains to the left edge and width = parent width.

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:child_view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parent_view
                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
```

Comment: Do you think it would work by adding 2 constraints to the sub_view for width and height(instead of left edge) and doing the whole "relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual multiplier:1.0" thing for both constraints?

Comment: Actually please ignore my first comment, how would you specify a constraint for an edge?

Comment: My solution = your solution, but i offered to set
left = left,
top = top,
width = width,
height = height.

Comment: Oh my bad. I thought you meant to add just 2, just left and width

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
[view.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:view.superview
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];
```